# Pipe git diff to git apply

Tags: git, shell, zsh, patch

Why won't this command work ?

```
git diff | git --git-dir=/other/location/.git --work-tree=/other/location apply
```

The following works perfectly:

```
git diff > /tmp/my.patch
cd /other/location && git apply /tmp/my.patch
```

`/other/location` is a mirror of the current directory.

With the piped command I get

```
error: patch failed: myfile.php:1
error: myfile.php: patch does not apply
```

Comment: Did you try using `git diff | git .... apply -` to tell `git-apply` to use patch data from standard input?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works for me (`git 2.6.3`):

```
git diff | git -C /other/location apply
```

From `man git`:

```
-C <path>
       Run as if git was started in <path> instead of the current working
       directory. When multiple -C options are given, each subsequent 
       non-absolute -C <path> is interpreted relative to
       the preceding -C <path>.
```

Comment: That doesn't help unfortunately. It's trying to apply the patch so its not an issue of it seeing the characters over the pipe.

Comment: FWIW, the `git -C <path>` switch is fairly new, so this won't work with older versions like 1.8.3 which is installed with various operating systems.